# Winform textbox not offering all keyboard options

Tags: winforms, textbox, ime, hindi, indic

I have been using StackOVerflow for years and it's very rare that I did not find my question being answered already. But in this case, either I am missing something obvious or no one had to do this before.

I am using dotnet 3.5 C# winform desktop application on windows XP. I have enabled language bar on XP and have installed more than one languages. For one of the languages, Hindi, I have installed more than one keyboards (input mode?), One that comes with XP (Hindi Traditional) and Remigton.

When I am using MSWord or Write pad and select my language as Hindi, I see in the language bar, a dropdown to select my keyboard (input mode?) I can choose from "Hindi Indic Input 2" or "Hindi Traditional". If I choose "Hindi Indic Input 2" I see in Settings 9 more options to choose from.

In my application, which is a simple winform application developed using C# dotnet 3.5, when the input focus is on any textbox, I do see the language bar and I can change my input language but in the language bar I do not see the option to change my keyboard (input mode). I want to be able to enter text in my text box either using "Tradional Hindi" or "Hindi Indic 2" but it only allows to enter text using "Hindi Traditional". Language bar does not show the dropdown to select keyboard.

Question: What do I have to do to unable the input mode/keyboard selection in langguage bar when focus is in my windows form application?